# Definite integral that give distance between two moving particles

Tags: kinematics, integration, calculus, distance

I have two particles $P_1$ and $P_2$ and I know how their coordinates change against time $(x_1(t)$, $y_1(t))$ and $(x_2(t)$, $y_2(t))$

I can easily get distance $L$ between them as
$$L(t)=\sqrt{{(x_2(t)-x_1(t))}^2+{(y_2(t)-y_1(t))}^2}.$$

Is there a way to express distance $L$ as definite integral?
$$L(T)=\int_{0}^{T}{f(t)dt}.$$

I would like to find $f(t)$ if possible.

Comment: Do you want to find the distance travelled in going from $P_1$ to $P_2 $or just the straight line distance between the two points ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $x_1 \neq x_2$ (ie, the line separating the two points is not vertical), you can parameterize the $x,y$ coordinates of the line separating $\mathbf{r}_1(t)$ and $\mathbf{r}_2(t)$ as follows
$$
y = y_1(t) + \frac{y_2(t) - y_1(t)}{x_2(t) - x_1(t) } x
$$
Then you want the [arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integration) of $y(x)$ from $x_1(t)$ to $x_2(t)$
\begin{eqnarray}
L(t) &=& \int_{x_1(t)}^{x_2(t)} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} dx \\
&=& \int_{x_1(t)}^{x_2(t)} \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{y_2(t)-y_1(t)}{x_2(t) - x_1(t)}\right)^2}dx
\end{eqnarray}
Given a parameterization $x(\lambda)$ for some parameter $\lambda$, you can use a substitution to replace the integral with one over $d\lambda$. Essentially you would replace $dx$ with $\frac{dx}{d\lambda}d\lambda$ and the bounds of the integral with $\lambda(x_i(t))$.

Of course you can do the integral trivially since the integrand doesn't depend on $x$, and you just get back the Pythagorean theorem
\begin{eqnarray}
L &=& \left(x_2(t) - x_1(t)\right) \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{y_2(t)-y_1(t)}{x_2(t) - x_1(t)}\right)^2} \\
&=& \sqrt{\left(x_2(t) - x_1(t)\right)^2 + \left(y_2(t)-y_1(t)\right)^2}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I don't really understand what lambda means in this context. Is it meant like time? If yes, will dx/dlambda become (v2(lambda)-v1(lambda))? And bounds would be from lambda1 to lambda2, right?